# Как изменить input "name" в зависимости от выбора select?

Tags: input

Вот например

```
<input name="full_1" value="" type="text">

<select id="options">
    <option value="full_1">Кат1</option>
    <option value="full_2">Кат2</option>
    <option value="full_3">Кат3</option>
</select>
```

По умолчанию input name="full_1", а если выбрать с списка, то что бы менялось name на full_2 или full_3 , как реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function rename(){
var field = document.getElementById("input");
var e = document.getElementById("options");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
field.setAttribute("name", strUser);
}
```

```html
<input name="full_1" value="" type="text" id="input">

<select id="options" onchange="rename();">
    <option value="full_1">Кат1</option>
    <option value="full_2">Кат2</option>
    <option value="full_3">Кат3</option>
</select>
```